# daterangepicker with webpack fails

Tags: jquery, webpack, daterangepicker

I installed [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) over webpack so far all the dependencies are loaded

```
yarn add moment
yarn add daterangepicker
```

but when I try to include I get `daterangepicker is not a function`

```
import 'moment'
import 'daterangepicker'


//init
console.log($('#mydaterange')) //exists
$('#mydaterange').daterangepicker()
```

from the error stack I can not relay on any dependency. Is there a proper way to use daterangepicker with webpack

Comment: Can you please print your webpack config and package.json?

Comment: Thanks I got it working between by adding new `webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   moment: 'moment',
   daterangepicker: 'daterangepicker'
  }),`

Answer (score 0):

Install the `imports-loader` webpack plugin and then you need to disable AMD with the additionalCode option https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/#additionalcode

You can specify the option inline as:

```js
import 'imports-loader?additionalCode=var%20define%20=%20false;!daterangepicker'
```

More info here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader#additionalcode